Анимация затемнения в Юнити
Что мне делать, анимация лежит в канвасе, а перезагрузка сцены в контролере персонажем.
Перенести из персонажа не могу потому что у меня стоит там условие что при падение перезагрузка сцены, и то что если жизни меньше одного перезагрузка сцены.
Я пробовал timeToRespawn но это был совет от говнокодера с ютуба и он не помог потому что юнити наотрез его не воспринимает.
Помогите пожалуйста может я както могу перенести переменные с контролера в канвас, например жизни или позицию игрока?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вам нужен компонент SceneManager с его прекрасным методом LoadScene().
Создаёте условие, при котором будет выполнятся код с загрузкой сцены,например:
private void HeroIsDead()
{
    if(_currentHealth <= 0)
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene Name");
}

